# How to write logs in Phonegap App Development?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have developed my app in phonegap. I need to generate log due to some issue. How can I generate it?

Comment: why dont you try `console.log();`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean log for debug, just use `console.log(<your text>)` and open developer tools / Web inspector to see it. Also can be viewed in LogCat

Comment: I am using Phonegap. Can you please elaborate how to see the log here. 
Even if I use console.log() I am not getting any response.

Comment: Elaborate first your question. Are you developing android, los, in simulator, chrome, real device?